# How to display the text in particular direction(swipe direction) from particular point in android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I want to display the text on image in selected touch portion and should be in direction where we swipe. Need to launch the EditText to enter the text.
How to display the text in particular direction(swipe direction) from particular point?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is backed by a Bitmap then probably the easiest thing to do would be to use one of Canvas's [drawText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) in combination with [rotate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29). If you want to stay away from that though, or simply want to apply effects to your text, you can always use a plain TextView with a [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) set to last for 0 seconds but setFillAfter to true. This will get you the desired visual effect but keep in mind that the bounding box used for touch events will not alter. Therefore the rotated view should not be made clickable. Hope that helps.